# Every element of a ring $A$ is integral over the ring $A$. How?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

I am learning Integral Dependence for the first time. Every book says that the answer to my question is trivial but I don't see it. Please help!

Comment: A ring element $a$ satisfies $X - a \in A[X]$

Comment: If $a\in A$, it is the (unique) root of the polynomial $X-a\in A[X]$. Other justification: the module $A[a]=A$ is finitely generated over $A$

Comment: One of the preceding comments should be made an answer (perhaps with the word "monic" added), so that the stackexchange software doesn't treat the question as unanswered.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of integrality:

> **Definition:** Let $B$ be a ring, and let $A\subseteq B$ be a subring of $B.$ An element $b\in B$ is *integral* over $A$ if there exists a monic polynomial $f\in A[x]$ such that $f(b) = 0.$

Certainly $A\subseteq A$ is a subring of itself, so $a\in A$ is integral over $A$ if there exists a monic polynomial $f\in A[x]$ such that $f(a) = 0.$ Setting $f(x) = x - a,$ we see that $f(a) = a - a = 0.$ As a monic polynomial is one whose leading coefficient is $1,$ this produces an explicit monic polynomial that has $a\in A$ as a root. As $a$ was arbitrary, we have shown that every element of $A$ is integral over $A.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I was thinking of a polynomial p(x) in degree n>1 and wasn't sure how "a" could be root of that. But I should have thought about p(x)=x-a. Thank you once again.